# How to read from inputFileStream and split each line

Tags: java, file, inputstream, split

I have to read from input file **txtfile** that look like `mark;1001;3;4` there is a `';'` between each variable. I know how to read it if it's in separate lines, but I can't read it if its in the same line.

This is how I start:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.Buffer;

public class Try {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Name;
        int ID;
        Double quiz1 , quiz2;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileIN = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputST =new InputStreamReader(fileIN);
            BufferedReader  bufferRe = new BufferedReader(inputST);

            String line;

            while ((line = bufferRe.readLine()) != null) {
                // I tried many things, but nothing worked for me.
                // How could I use split here?
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("input is not found ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to split the line  mark;1001;3;4 into mark 1001 3 4?

Comment: `line.split(";")` is all you need.  What trouble did you have using it.

Comment: Split each line by using `string[] currentLine = line.split(";");`

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed your comment in the `while`. I hope I made the correct changes, because your comment was very hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Using split is the way to go...

```
while ( ( line = bufferRe.readLine())!= null) {
    for (String splitVal : line.split(";") {
         //Do whatever you need to with the splitVal value.
         //In you example it iterate 4 times with the values mark 1001 3 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution, which also works when you want things to work across newlines, is to use a `Scanner` with `;` as its delimiter:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(bufferRe);
s.useDelimiter(";");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.next());
}
-->
 mark
1001
3
4
```

This also allows you to use Scanner methods to eg. easily parse integers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method inside loop to get all your data in array.

```
String[] splited = line.split(";");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = bufferRe.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String retval : line.split(";", 2)) {
        System.out.println(retval);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
mark
1001;3;4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more aproach using StreamTokenizer

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(r);

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

     // print the stream tokens
     boolean eof = false;
     do {
        int token = st.nextToken();
        switch (token) {
           case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
              System.out.println("End of File encountered.");
              eof = true;
              break;
           case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
              System.out.println("End of Line encountered.");
              break;
           case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
              words.add(st.sval);
              break;
           case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
              numbers.add((int)st.nval);
              break;
           default:
              System.out.println((char) token + " encountered.");
              if (token == '!') {
                 eof = true;
              }
        }
     } while (!eof);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("input is not found ");
}
```